# jq how to merge two JSON streams into a single JSON stream

Tags: json, merge, stream, jq

How to merge two json streams/lists into a single stream of jsons like the following.

file 1:

```
{"key1": 1}
{"key1": 2}
{"key1": 3}
```

file 2:

```
{"key2": -1}
{"key2": -2}
{"key2": -3}
```

Expected output:

```
{"key1": 1, "key2": -1}
{"key1": 2, "key2": -2}
{"key1": 3, "key2": -3}
```

Comment: In the JSON world, those "lists" would normally be called "streams". https://clue.engineering/2018/introducing-reactphp-ndjson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a "streaming" solution that is more efficient (both memory-wise and otherwise) than one that requires that both files be read in their entirety before producing any output:

```
< file1.json jq -nc --slurpfile file2 file2.json '
  # For each item $s in the stream s,
  # emit [$s, $t] where $t is the corresponding item in the input array
  def zip(s):
    . as $in
    | foreach s as $s (-1; .+1; [$s, $in[.]]);

  $file2 | zip(inputs) | add
'
```

If your jq does not support the `--slurpfile` command-line option, then use `--argfile` instead.

### As a one-liner

```
foreach inputs as $s (-1; .+1; $s + $file2[.])
```